# Cannot insert timeuuid in Cassandra with Kundera

Tags: java, cassandra, kundera

I have this Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx ( id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY);
```

and this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxx", schema = "yyy")
   public class XXX {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public UUID id;
}
```

Upon persisting, I get:

> Exception in thread "main" com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GenerationType.AUTO Strategy not supported by this client :com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClient
>       at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:174)
>       at Importer.save(StayImporter.java:80)
>       at Importer.exec(StayImporter.java:92)
>       at Importer.main(StayImporter.java:100)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GenerationType.AUTO Strategy not supported by this client :com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClient
>       at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.IdGenerator.onAutoGenerator(IdGenerator.java:116)
>       at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.IdGenerator.generateAndSetId(IdGenerator.java:71)
>       at com.impetus.kundera.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder.getNode(ObjectGraphBuilder.java:111)
>       at com.impetus.kundera.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder.getObjectGraph(ObjectGraphBuilder.java:75)
>       at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.PersistenceDelegator.persist(PersistenceDelegator.java:135)
>       at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:168)
>       ... 8 more

This is my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus</id>
        <name>Kundera Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.impetus.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>kundera-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs:

> GenerationType.AUTO Strategy not supported by this client com.impetus.client.cassandra.pelops.PelopsClient

I suggest you to use Thrift client. You can do this by changing `kundera.client.lookup.class` property in `persistence.xml` to the following:

```
<property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />
```

Also, I suggest you to use [latest version of Kundera-Cassandra](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.impetus.kundera.client/kundera-cassandra).

Comment: It works, many thanks!

I also commented out the lines about ehcache in persistence.xml:

            <!--<property name="kundera.cache.provider.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-test.xml"/>-->